# Trying to find $S_y $ eigenspinors for a spin = 1 particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, representation-theory

I know how to construct Sy for spin = 1 case from the raising and lowering operators.
I get
$$
S_y=\frac{i\hbar}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
From what I have seen, the eigenspinor for $\hbar$ is found by solving

$$
\frac{i\hbar}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma
\end{pmatrix} = 
\hbar \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma
\end{pmatrix}
$$
That leaves me with three equations
$$
-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \beta = \alpha\\
\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \alpha - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\gamma = \beta\\
\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \beta = \gamma\\
$$
My difficulty lies in how to construct the eigenspinor from these values. Is it simply
$$
\chi_{+}^y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 1 \\ \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$?

Armed with the eigenspinor for $S_y$ basis and eigenvalue $\hbar$, how do I compute the probability that some spin state, say
$$
\chi = \mathcal{N}\begin{pmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c
\end{pmatrix}$$

in in that state?

My instincts are to construct
$$
\left|\langle \chi | \chi_+^y \rangle\right|^2
$$
but every time I try this with the specific spin state I am interested in, I get the probability = 1. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Remember that to get the probabilities, you have to take the *square of the modulus* of the expansion coefficient.

Comment: The easiest way to find "y" eigenstates for spin 1 is take the spherical harmonics in cartesian coordinates : $Y_1^m(x, y, z)$ and sub in $Y_1^m(z, x, y)$. If you do the real spherical harmonics that chemist like, for $L=1$, they are just $x, y, z$, so you just say, make that $z, x, y$.  It may seem trivial, but that is the nature of "$z$ is an arbitrary axis".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it simply
> $$
> \chi_{+}^y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
> -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 1 \\ \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$?

Yes, the above expression, or the above expression times any phase is an appropriate eigenfunction.

Specifically:
$$
\chi_{+}^y=\frac{e^{i\phi}}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 1 \\ \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for any fixed real $\phi$ will work.

E.g.:
$$
\chi_{+}^y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 1 \\ \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
E.g.:
$$
\chi_{+}^y=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 1 \\ \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
etc.

> $$
> \chi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ i\sqrt{2} \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}
> $$

> but if I try to compute $\langle \chi_{+}^y|\chi \rangle$ to find the probability I end up with a complex expression. I was expecting a real number.

Yes, probabilities have to be real numbers between 0 and 1.

Your issues with the calculation are two-fold. First, the state $\chi$ appears to be improperly normalized. So, normalize it (or correct a typo in your post if that is the issue). Second, what you have computed is the probability *amplitude*, not the probability. You need to take the absolute square of the value you computed. I.e., you need $|\langle \chi_{+}^y|\chi \rangle|^2$ not $\langle \chi_{+}^y|\chi \rangle$.